# Equality from distance of point in segment in inner product norm

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

For some reason I can't seem to get this simple result:
$c = ta+(1-t)b$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ , iff $||b-a|| = ||b-c||+||c-a|| $
Where $||\cdot||$ comes from an inner product.
Edit:
I see now how to prove the forward direction, but I'm having difficulty with the converse...

Comment: What have you tried? The forward direction is straight forward computation: assume $c=ta+(1-t)b$ and plug it into $\Vert b-c\Vert+\Vert c-a\Vert$

Comment: Just simplify the expression $$\Vert b-ta-(1-t)b\Vert+\Vert ta+(1-t)b-a\Vert$$ and see if you can get it to $\Vert b-a\Vert$.

Comment: @Dave Just edited in my attempt

Comment: @Dave Found my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the converse, take the equation $||b-a||-||c-b||=||c-a||$ and square it for the result:

$||b||^2-a\cdot b-b\cdot c+a\cdot c=||b-a||\hspace{0.1cm}||c-b||$

which can be conveniently rewritten as:

$(b-c)\cdot(b-a)=||b-c||\hspace{0.15cm}||b-a||$ for all vectors a,b,c.

However the Schwarz inequality tells us that:

$(b-c)\cdot(b-a)\leq||b-c||\hspace{0.15cm}||b-a||$ with the equality being true iff $b-c=t(b-a), t\in \mathbb{R}$. By rearranging the latter equation the proof of the converse is complete.